# how can i open a url to current ios app instead of Safari?

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

Suppose i have one button on my app, and when click it, it calls a webpage or url.

Now What I want to do is, i want to open that webpage on my app screen instead of Safari or any other browser?

i think it's possible with web-view.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview

Comment: Yes, you need to use a web view or `SFSafariViewController`

Comment: @Paulw11 , i don't want to open link in safari or any browser.

Comment: [`SFSafariViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/sfsafariviewcontroller) is a view controller that you present in your app.  It has provides isolation between your app and the browser view which means you can use things like autofill

Comment: @Paul11 understood.

Comment: You surely tried _something_. SO is not a free code writing website. Without showing at least some (research) effort, you're highly unlikely to receive an answer here.

Answer (score 0):

You must use a web view:

```
import WebKit

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let url = URL(string: "https://google.com")!
        let webView = WKWebView(frame: view.bounds)
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        view.addSubview(webView)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create your own web view (or controller), then try to load the URL on it. Example:

```swift
import WebKit

class MyWebViewController: UIViewController {
    private let webView = WKWebView()
    private let urlString: String
    
    init(url: String) {
        self.urlString = url
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: .main)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.addSubview(webView)
        webView.frame = view.bounds
        webView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleLeftMargin, .flexibleTopMargin, .flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
        
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
    }
}
```